# Using libraries without NPM install with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to use brain.js library in my project, but unfornately it is impossible to install brain.js with NPM at now.

On a simple website without React it is easy to import brain.js with `<script src="//unpkg.com/brain.js"></script>`  tags . After that I can simply init a new instance with `const network = new brain.NeuralNetwork();`

But with React I cannot manage to import it now as I wrote and I want to find a solution for that.
I tried this method, but did not work :

In **AIsource** ( AIsource.js ) component :

```
export default function AIsource() {
  return (
    I COPIED HERE THE CONTENT OF CDN JAVASCRIPT FILE
  )
}
```

In **Simple** ( Simple.js ) component :

```
import AIsource from './AIsource'
export default function Simple() {
      return (
        const network = new brain.NeuralNetwork();
      )
}
```

But I get an error : `brain is not defined`. So I think the importing did not worked.

Comment: First you never execute `AIsource`,  second you might find `brain` will now be inside the closure you have just created, so you might want to also `return brain`.

Comment: @Keith Thank you. Do you know a better/easier method instead of this to import brain.js to React?

Comment: You could just import `brain.js` the old fashioned way, `<script src=""/>` and you will get a global `brain`.

Comment: @Keith I tried the old fashioned way, but I still get brain is not defined error . I think the script loads too slow and the component want to access brain before the <script src > loads .